# Concatenate PDFs but extend pdf's to be even number of pages

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I want to concatenate a bunch of PDFs but for printing purposes I would prefer that empty pages are added to each document that have an odd number of pages. Can I do this with PDFTK?

Comment: Can you use LaTeX?

Comment: Sure I can @terdon

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple little script that will iterate over all pdf files in the current directory and concatenate them into a single PDF, using LaTeX. PDFs with an odd number of pages will have an extra blank page added after them:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cat<<EoF > all.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
EoF

## rename the PDFs to something safe
c=0;
for f in *pdf
do
        ## Link the PDF with a safe name
        ln -s "$f" "$c".pdf
        ## Include the PDF in the tex file
        printf '\includepdf[pages=-]{%s.pdf}\n' "$c" >> all.tex;
        ## Get the number of pages
        pages=$(pdfinfo "$c".pdf | grep -oP '^Pages:\s*\K\d+')
        ## Add an empty page if they are odd
        [[ $(expr "$pages" % 2) != 0 ]] && 
            printf '%s\n' "\newpage\null" >> all.tex

        ((c++));
done

printf '\\end{document}' >> all.tex;
pdflatex all.tex
```

Since this is LaTeX, you can do all sorts of extra stuff. For example, you can have each PDF in its own section, with a clickable table of contents:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cat<<EoF > all.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,linktoc=page]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
EoF
## rename the PDFs to something safe
c=0;
for f in *pdf
do
        ## Link the PDF with a safe name
        ln -s "$f" "$c".pdf
        ## Include the PDF in the tex file
        cat<<EoF >> all.tex
\section{${f//.pdf}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{$c.pdf}
EoF
        ## Get the number of pages
        pages=$(pdfinfo "$c".pdf | grep -oP '^Pages:\s*\K\d+')
        ## This time, because each PDF has its own section title
        ## we want to add a blank page to the even numbered ones
        [[ $(expr "$pages" % 2) = 0 ]] && 
            printf '%s\n' "\newpage\null\newpage" >> all.tex

        ((c++));
done

printf '\\end{document}' >> all.tex;
## Need to run it twice to build the ToC
pdflatex all.tex; pdflatex all.tex;
```

Comment: may be `\cleardoublepage` ?

Comment: I'd like to suggest adding ``\pagenumbering{gobble}`` after ``\documentclass{article}`` to switch off the page numbering of the added empty pages.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly. Just create a blank page with (for example)

```
echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - blank.pdf
```

and add `blank.pdf` to every document that has an odd number of pages. E.g.

```
pdftk \
BLANK=blank.pdf \
A=foo1.pdf \
B=foo2.pdf \
C=foo3.pdf \
cat A BLANK B BLANK C \
output bar.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a more automated way since I have *many* PDFs.

Comment: Ah, An automated way should also be possible, you'd have to ask pdfinfo for the size of the PDFs and proceed accordingly. You should make clear in your question that you are looking for an automated method, and also perhaps include an example of what you have in mind.

Comment: Interesting! I'll try to make something.

Answer (score 0):

For future wanderers like myself. I wrote a script combining the answer from @Faheem Mitha and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26030976)

```
#!/bin/sh
# USAGE: ./concat-pdf.sh *.pdf output-file.pdf

ALL_FILES=""
BLANK_FILE="/tmp/blank.pdf"

for OUTPUT_FILE; do true; done
if test -f "$OUTPUT_FILE"; then
    echo "$OUTPUT_FILE already exists"
    exit 1
fi

echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - $BLANK_FILE
for PDF_FILE; do
    if [ "$PDF_FILE" != "$OUTPUT_FILE" ]; then
        pages=$(strings < "$PDF_FILE" | sed -n 's|.*Count -\{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*|\1|p' | sort -rn | head -n 1)
        ALL_FILES="$ALL_FILES \"$PDF_FILE\""
        [ $((pages%2)) -ne 0 ] && ALL_FILES="$ALL_FILES $BLANK_FILE"
    fi
done

echo "pdftk $ALL_FILES cat output \"$OUTPUT_FILE\""

pdftk $ALL_FILES cat output "$OUTPUT_FILE"

rm -f $BLANK_FILE
```

Comment: This answer doesn't escape filenames properly and fails when they contain spaces

Comment: Thanks, hopefully it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps I used to have blank page after every page of my Pdf file with Pdftk in Ubuntu

1-Install pdftk if you haven't already

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

2-Create a blank PDF file named blank.pdf. You can use the convert command from the ImageMagick package to create a blank image and then convert it to PDF. Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
convert -size 595x842 xc:white blank.jpg
convert blank.jpg blank.pdf
```

if you got security policy error, open the policy.xml file using a text editor with root privileges. For example, you can use the following command to open it with the nano editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Change the value of the rights attribute from "none" to "read|write" for PDF. The modified line should look like this:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

3- Now navigate to the directory where your PDF file is located then use the following commands

```
pdftk input.pdf burst output burst_output%d.pdf
pdftk $(for f in burst_output*.pdf; do echo -n "$f blank.pdf "; done) cat output final.pdf
```

put the name of your input file instead of "input".

Now your final.pdf is ready!
You can delete the splitted pages after this.

Comment: It's not clear whether your answer will insert a blank page at the end, or after every existing page. Also, inserting an image just to create a blank page is suboptimal, and will conflict if they background colour is changed. Probably the simplest way to get a PDF with a blank page is `echo showpage | ps2pdf - /tmp/blank.pdf` (`ps2pdf` is usually in the `ghostscript` or `gs` package)

Comment: @MartinKealey
After every existing page as I wrote in my first sentence. 
Thanks for your suggestion about the blank page.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, which is to insert one blank page at the end of each PDF if it currently has an odd number of pages. (This might be useful if they're subsequently concatenated.)